# equals not matching though declared

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML Text

```
S1/7/1
```

And the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">

                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:variable name="ChpnMatch">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(regex-group(1),1,1)"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="regex1">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$ChpnMatch = 'U'">
                                    <xsl:text>HKWB2015EDSUPP2_CH_S4</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$ChpnMatch = 'B|D|E|L|R|F|H|K|Q|S'">
                                    <xsl:text>HKWB2015EDSUPP2_CH_S3</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:text>HKWB2015EDSUPP2_CH_S1</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <a href="{concat('er:#',$regex1,'/P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>

                            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>

    </xsl:template>
```

Here there is a case `<xsl:when test="$ChpnMatch = 'B|D|E|L|R|F|H|K|Q|S'">`, which is the actual match the result should be `HKWB2015EDSUPP2_CH_S3`, but the result that is caught is `HKWB2015EDSUPP2_CH_S1` (which is `otherwise block`). can you please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix this.

Here is [Working Demo](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJL)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare a string to a sequence of other strings then you need e.g. `'S' = ('A', 'B', 'D', 'S')` so I think instead of `xsl:when test="$ChpnMatch = 'B|D|E|L|R|F|H|K|Q|S'"` you want `xsl:when test="$ChpnMatch = ('B', 'D', 'E', 'L', 'R', 'F', 'H', 'K', 'Q', 'S')"`. That checks whether `$ChpnMatch` is equal to at least one of the strings in the sequence `('B', 'D', 'E', 'L', 'R', 'F', 'H', 'K', 'Q', 'S')`.